Utilizing cloud storage APIs for document access and web dav
Currently we are using Box and Onedrive to store files from our web application as they have microsoft tools built in for live editing of the document(docx, pdf, etc) and their access also is authenticated using access tokens which they use to log in to our application so there is no duplication(Azure active directory for onedrive and Okta single sign on for box). However, in order to still restrict access of our applications folder to our users we share the folder the files reside in with individual users and on our UI we just pull their file links from their respective APIs. This works and hasnt been a problem but one issue we have is in either of these cloud platform sharing access to the folder allows the user to navigate through the folder in the Box UI or OneDrive UI. Is there a way we are not sharing the the folders with users but instead just each individual document without worrying about security issues? For instance, I was thinking maybe a temporary link would suffice rather than granting permanant access to the shared folder? I am unsure how to approach this.
